# How do I get NSJSONSerialization to output a boolean as true or false?

Tags: ios, json, boolean

I'm using NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject to serialize my classes to JSON.  When it serializes a BOOL, it gives it the value 1 or 0 in the JSON string.  I need this to be true or false instead.  Is this possible to do generically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Foundation Object for a Bool is `NSNumber` `numberWithBool`, which becomes either 0 or 1. We have no `Bool` Object. Same go for reading `JSON`. True/false will become a `NSNumber` again.

You could create an `Bool` Class and build your own parser. Arrays are Arrays and `JSON` Objects are `NSDictionary`. You can query the keys, test what Class lies behind and build the `JSON` String from this.

Comment: thanks, I created my own JSONBool class and was able to get it working like that

Comment: @TritonMan mind posting more of the code in the JSONBool class?  Trying to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Yes, the way how NSJSONSerialization works changed over the years. Please note the date when this question was asked and answered.

Comment: @Julian's answer below with `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]` is much simpler nowadays

Answer (score 30):

When I create `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]`, the NSJSONSerialization returns the word "false" in the JSON string.

**EDIT** With the new shortcuts you can also use these handy guys:

```
@(YES) /   @(NO)
@(1)   /   @(0)
@YES   /   @NO
@1     /   @0
```

This way you can avoid something like looping through your values. I want the exact opposite behavior but have `NSNumber` objects. So I have to loop...

**EDIT II**

[mbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428209/mbi) pointed out in the comments that there is a difference between iOS versions. So here is an iOS9 test:

```
NSDictionary *data = @{
    @"a": @(YES),
    @"b": @YES,
    @"c": @(1),
    @"d": @1
};
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:0 error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

2016-07-05 02:23:43.964 Test App[24581:6231996] {"a":true,"b":true,"c":1,"d":1}
```

Comment: There is a little caveat between iOS versions here!

This code
`[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{ @"Test1" : @YES, @"Test2" : @(YES), @"Test3" : @true, @"Test4" : @(true) } options:nil error:nil]`
produces this json on iOS 9
`{"Test4":true,"Test3":true,"Test2":true,"Test1":true}`
but produces this json on iOS 8 and below
`{"Test4":1,"Test3":1,"Test2":true,"Test1":true}`

Comment: Interesting... Thanks for this observation!

Comment: No, I didnt see that. I will delete my comment. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 15):

Just ran across this myself, not sure if this is the best answer but...

Make sure to use @YES or @NO, then your outputted json will have true / false in it:

```
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"test": @YES} options:0 error: nil];
```

So you will have to turn your other "booleans" / boolean like values -> @YES / @NO when putting into the dictionary for dataWithJSONObject.

```
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"test": (boolLikeValue ? @YES : @NO)} options:0 error: nil];
```

Comment: I find this helpful since not always one can use literals directly. e.g. In a function receiving a `BOOL` parameter, you'll need to convert the primitive `BOOL` to one of the acknowledgeable `@BOOL` literals` @YES` and `@NO`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to output a boolean (true/false) with NSJSONSerialization by using **kCFBooleanTrue** and **kCFBooleanFalse** :

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kCFBooleanTrue, @"key_1",
                           kCFBooleanFalse, @"key_2",
                           nil]
```

then

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue when using CoreData's boolean, which is stored as NSNumber too. The easiest solution for me was using @():

```
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"bool": @([object.value boolValue])} options:0 error: nil];
```

I guess @() does recognize the BOOL value and initialize the NSNumber with numberWithBool: which leads to true/false in JSON

Answer (score 1):

I just hit the issue on iOS9.
My case is that I have a CoreData property `workout.private` which is bool mapped to NSNumber* due to CoreData handling.

When creating JSON
`[NSNumber numberWithBool:workout.private.boolValue]` sets expected true/false in JSON, but just `workout.private` or @(workout.private.boolValue) sets "1" or "0".