# How to create true/false in JSON in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

How do I get true/false (instead of "true"/"false") in json from a NSDictionary using NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject? What keys should I store in the dictionary to get that?

Comment: This is the one area where mapping between JSON and Objective-C objects is slightly less than perfect, but generally `@YES`/`@NO` will work, as stated below.  Do note, though that this has nothing to do with "keys".  The keys in a dictionary/JSON "object" need to be strings.  It's the *values* we're talking about.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Stop the harassment please.

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615451/how-do-i-get-nsjsonserialization-to-output-a-boolean-as-true-or-false

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSNumber` objects containing a `BOOL` are mapped to JSON "true" and "false".
So just use `@YES`, `@NO`, or generally `@(someBOOL)`. For example:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"this is": @YES};
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// {"this is":true}
```

Comment: Why is NSJSONSerialization able to distinguish between @YES vs @(1) and output true for former and 1 for latter?

Comment: @Boon: It probably uses the `objCType` method to get information about the type of the value.

Comment: @Boon Add code like this: `NSNumber *aBool = @YES; NSNumber *anInt = @1;`. Now use the debugger to look at the internal types generated by those two lines. You actually get two different internal types for those two objects.