# Is it possible to store literal booleans in JSON with the NSJSONSerialization class?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

Objective-C enforces the conversion of a `BOOL` to an `NSNumber` for storage in an `NSDictionary` which is converted to JSON by `NSJSONSerialization`.

Is it possible to write literal boolean values (`true` or `false` *with no string quotations*) to JSON instead of `0` and `1`? This would make interactions with servers that don't support 0 or 1 a lot easier.

For an example, if I had a boolean value being saved in an `NSDictionary` using `@YES`/`@NO`, `[NSNumber numberWithBool:BOOL]`, etc. `NSJSONSerialization` would output it like this:

```
{
    "excludes": 1
}
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
{
    "excludes": true
}
```

Any ideas or solutions? Android makes this much easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create true/false in JSON in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411119/how-to-create-true-false-in-json-in-objective-c)

Comment: @MartinR same concept but the accepted answer there doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you show a complete example? It worked for me when I tested it.

Comment: @MartinR well I have a class that contains a method called "toJSON" that returns data which is passed to the serializer. It looks like this: http://pastebin.com/Q1AnJpDv, excludes is a `BOOL`. Changing that excludes line to "@"excludes": [self excludes] ? @YES : @NO};" doesn't work either.

Comment: That is strange. I just tried it with `@{@"foo": @YES, @"bar": @NO}` and got the JSON data `{"foo":true,"bar":false}` .

Comment: @MartinR how do you use `NSJSONSerialization` when you convert the dictionary?

Comment: Exactly as here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22411217/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR oh weird, you're right. It appears that something happens in between generating the NSData and transmitting it via the AFNetworking library.