# Using JSONSerialization() to dynamically figure out boolean values

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.1

I am getting a JSON string from the server (or file).

I want to parse that JSON string and **dynamically** figure out each of the value types.

However, when it comes to boolean values, `JSONSerialization` just converts the value to `0` or `1`, and the code can't differentiate whether "0" is a `Double`, `Int`, or `Bool`.

I want to recognize whether the value is a `Bool` without explicitly knowing that a specific key corresponds to a `Bool` value. What am I doing wrong, or what could I do differently?

```
// What currently is happening:
let jsonString = "{\"boolean_key\" : true}"
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]

json["boolean_key"] is Double // true
json["boolean_key"] is Int // true
json["boolean_key"] is Bool // true

// What I would like to happen is below (the issue doesn't happen if I don't use JSONSerialization):
let customJson: [String:Any] = [
    "boolean_key" : true
]

customJson["boolean_key"] is Double // false
customJson["boolean_key"] is Int // false
customJson["boolean_key"] is Bool // true
```

Related:

- [How do I get NSJSONSerialization to output a boolean as true or false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615451/how-do-i-get-nsjsonserialization-to-output-a-boolean-as-true-or-false)
- [Is there a correct way to determine that an NSNumber is derived from a Bool using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215680/is-there-a-correct-way-to-determine-that-an-nsnumber-is-derived-from-a-bool-usin/30223989#30223989)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `JSONSerialization`, any Bool values (`true` or `false`) get converted to `NSNumber` instances which is why the use of `is Double`, `is Int`, and `is Bool` all return true since `NSNumber` can be converted to all of those types.

You also get an `NSNumber` instance for actual numbers in the JSON.

But the good news is that in reality, you actually get special internal subclasses of `NSNumber`. The boolean values actually give you `__NSCFBoolean` while actual numbers give you `__NSCFNumber`. Of course you don't actually want to check for those internal types.

Here is a fuller example showing the above plus a workable solution to check for an actual boolean versus a "normal" number.

```
let jsonString = "{\"boolean_key\" : true, \"int_key\" : 1}"
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [String:Any]

print(type(of: json["boolean_key"]!)) // __NSCFBoolean
json["boolean_key"] is Double // true
json["boolean_key"] is Int // true
json["boolean_key"] is Bool // true

print(type(of: json["int_key"]!)) // __NSCFNumber
json["int_key"] is Double // true
json["int_key"] is Int // true
json["int_key"] is Bool // true

print(type(of: json["boolean_key"]!) == type(of: NSNumber(value: true))) // true
print(type(of: json["boolean_key"]!) == type(of: NSNumber(value: 1))) // false
print(type(of: json["int_key"]!) == type(of: NSNumber(value: 0))) // true
print(type(of: json["int_key"]!) == type(of: NSNumber(value: true))) // false
```

Comment: You _can_ actually check for those internal types if you go to the CF level where they're public; see my answer.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I didn't say you can't check for the internal types. I suggested that you shouldn't because, well, they are internal. Your check is fine. I mean not to check for `__NSCFBoolean`.

Comment: `__NSCFBoolean` is just a toll-free-bridge for `CFBoolean`, which we can check for easily enough.

Comment: thank you very much, I started to think a similar route because when doing a pretty-print of the dictionary, it was able to print the fact that they are boolean values

Comment: I like the fact that you aren't "hard-coding" the actual type so this seems like the safest route

Answer (score 13):

This confusion is a result of the "feature" of all the wonderful magic built into the Swift<->Objective-C bridge. Specifically, the `is` and `as` keywords don't behave the way you'd expect, because the `JSONSerialization` object, being actually written in Objective-C, is storing these numbers not as Swift `Int`s, `Double`s, or `Bool`s, but instead as `NSNumber` objects, and the bridge just magically makes `is` and `as` convert `NSNumber`s to any Swift numeric types that they can be converted to. So that is why `is` gives you `true` for every `NSNumber` type.

Fortunately, we can get around this by casting the number value to `NSNumber` instead, thus avoiding the bridge. From there, we run into *more* bridging shenanigans, because `NSNumber` is toll-free bridged to `CFBoolean` for Booleans, and `CFNumber` for most other things. So if we jump through all the hoops to get down to the CF level, we can do things like:

```
if let num = json["boolean_key"] as? NSNumber {
    switch CFGetTypeID(num as CFTypeRef) {
        case CFBooleanGetTypeID():
            print("Boolean")
        case CFNumberGetTypeID():
            switch CFNumberGetType(num as CFNumber) {
            case .sInt8Type:
                print("Int8")
            case .sInt16Type:
                print("Int16")
            case .sInt32Type:
                print("Int32")
            case .sInt64Type:
                print("Int64")
            case .doubleType:
                print("Double")
            default:
                print("some other num type")
            }
        default:
            print("Something else")
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, I started to think a similar route because when doing a pretty-print of the dictionary, it was able to print the fact that they are boolean values

Answer (score 5):

Because `JSONSerialization` converts each of the values to an `NSNumber`, this can be achieved by trying to figure out what each `NSNumber` instance is underneath: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30223989/826435

```
let jsonString = "{ \"boolean_key\" : true, \"integer_key\" : 1 }"
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]

extension NSNumber {
    var isBool: Bool {
        return type(of: self) == type(of: NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true))
    }
}

(json["boolean_key"] as! NSNumber).isBool // true
(json["integer_key"] as! NSNumber).isBool // false
```

*(Note: I already got similar [better] answers as I was typing this up, but I figured to leave my answer for anyone else looking at different approaches)*